# Consultas SPARQL en Protégé - ¿Como?

Tags: sql, sintaxis, datos, enlace, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo dificultades para formular consultas en la pestaña SPARQL de Protégé de mi ontología

Entiendo que la sintaxis de SPARQL utiliza tripletas de sujetos predicados y objetos
Al momento de ejecutar la consulta

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
    WHERE { ?s ?p ?o. }
```

Entendería por los tutoriales y explicaciones que he visto que estos mismos son los sujetos predicados y objetos que debo colocar en el WHERE de la sentencia para obtener los datos que deseo por ejemplo

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
    WHERE { ?s ?utiliza ?GAS91.}
```

Mi objetivo con esta consulta es obtener los modelos de auto que utilizan GAS91 o en todo caso los sujetos
Pero la misma no me trae resultados.

Agradezco una ayuda entendiendo cual es mi error y/o validando como se debe construir la consulta

Dejo archivo fuente de la ontología
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KVqRA-g4dsHt40WGHSaSCnIgdo5AGvsl?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Hola de acuerdo a lo que entiendo seria asi lo que deseas consultar. Espero que te sirva

PREFIX concesionaros_auto_pma: http://www.semanticweb.org/b7_es/ontologies/2022/3/concesionaros_auto_pma/1.0.0#

SELECT *
WHERE {?x concesionaros_auto_pma:utiliza concesionaros_auto_pma:GAS91}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]